# React Forms: Explaining the handleChange() function

Tags: reactjs, forms, form-submit

I am following this [React tutorial](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html), and I am trying to understand everything going on in the following code segment. Could someone explain what the `handleChange()` is doing and why it is important?

Is it for storing the inputted information so the back-end can process/store it?

```
class NameForm extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {value: ''};

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({value: event.target.value});
  }

  handleSubmit(event) {
    alert('A name was submitted: ' + this.state.value);
    event.preventDefault();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        <label>
          Name:
          <input type="text" value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange} />
        </label>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
      </form>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**handleChange** is Calling whenever you are entering any text to input **Name**
And

```
`
  handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({value: event.target.value});
  }
`
```

This is updating your state's `this.state` value and the same state's value used by input to show the current input `value={this.state.value}`  by you.

Take An example Suppose that you enter "Farro" as input, every time you enter **handleChange** will be called and update state value As "Farro" and in input field will show "Farro".

Answer (score 2):

The `this.handleChange` is triggered by the input element and triggers the changing of the `this.state.value` property which in turn changes the value of the input field. This is important because react uses states to display information in the DOM.

You could name the `handleChange` whatever you want just as long as it is triggered from the input field & the value updates the state.

here is some additional reading: https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html